# How to prevent elements from resizing when zooming in for irresponsive design?

Tags: html, css, interface, viewport

How to make a website get treated like in image when window resizing? I don't know if this could be done with the viewport or not. I have looked at some answers and most of them say that it not possible or not a standard. Yet on this very site you can see when zooming in that elements do not get resized or at least the element to window size ratio is always the same. but when you go to a website like https://www.lynda.com/ you can see the elements resizing when zooming in and there is never a scrollbar for the width unlike stackoverflow. So how can someone site's be like stackoverflow in that regard? because lynda.com way seems to be the default.

Thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 0):

If I got it correctly, you are interested in these concepts:

- Fixed layout/design: SO like layout, elements do not react if viewport is changes
- Response layout/design: Lynda like layout, elements change or even disappear, if viewport becomes small enough

A nice, short and illustrative presentation can be found [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/whats-the-difference-between-fixed-fluid-adaptive-and-responsive-web-design-treehouse), where you can also find out about other design modes.